# Oracle regex replace multiple occurrences of a string surrounded by commas

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I am looking for a way to replace (remove / replace with '') a character string in a comma-separated list of values in a column in an Oracle SQL database. For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
select ('SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all
select ('PK,SL') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('SL,SL') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('SL') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,SL,SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,OSL,SL,PK') as col1 from dual
union all 
select ('PI,SL,SLR,PK') as col1 from dual

COL1
-----
SL,PK
PK,SL
SL,SL
SL
PK
PI,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK
PI,OSL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SLR,PK
```

I am looking to replace all occurrences of the substring 'SL', strictly (i.e. not including 'OSL'), with an empty string, `''`. **The ideal result would look like this**:

```
COL2
-----
,PK
PK,
,
(null)
PK
PI,,PK
PI,,,PK
PI,,,,PK
PI,,,,,PK
PI,OSL,,PK
PI,,SLR,PK
```

I have tried to use the `regexp_replace` function, but it only eliminates every other occurence, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    regexp_replace(col1,'(^|,)(SL)($|,)','\1' || '' || '\3',1,0,'imn') as col2
FROM (
    SELECT ('SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PK,SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('SL,SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('PI,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,OSL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SLR,PK') as col1 FROM dual
)

COL1                COL2
-----               -----
SL,PK               ,PK
PK,SL               PK,
SL,SL               ,SL
SL                  (null)
PK                  PK
PI,SL,PK            PI,,PK
PI,SL,SL,PK         PI,,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK      PI,,SL,,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK   PI,,SL,,SL,PK
PI,OSL,SL,PK        PI,OSL,,PK
PI,SL,SLR,PK        PI,,SLR,PK
```

I have achieved my goal successfully in other regex implementations that have the word boundary `\b` construct available, but have not found a solution for Oracle's regex.

**UPDATE**

1. **Version**: We are on Oracle version 11g.
2. Addition example case `PI,SL,SLR,PK`
3. Additional example cases `PK,SL`, `SL,SL`, `SL`, `PK`

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use?

Comment: @wolφi my apologies for excluding that info. We are on 11g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because Oracle's regex moves the matching position forward after a match you need to do regexp double times unfortunately

```
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'(^|,)(SL)(\W|$)','\1\3',1,0,'imn') ,'(^|,)(SL)(\W|$)','\1\3',1,0,'imn')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if there are other letters after the 'SL' before the comma. Similar to how there can be letters before, as in the 'OSL' example, there can be letters after, i.e. 'SLR'. I have added this example case to the question as well.

Comment: then I don’t see a better alternative than making a second pass with a replacement. `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'(^|,)(SL)(\W|$)','\1\3',1,0,'imn') ,'(^|,)(SL)(\W|$)','\1\3',1,0,'imn')`

Comment: It's funny you mention that, that's actually what I just stumbled upon while I was trying different scenarios. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Single `regexp_replace` is posible (with some `replace`pre and post processing)  - see alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose a special character that doesn't appear in the string - I'm using semicolon (`;`) you may follow this steps

1) double each comma to comma + semicolon

2) perform your regexp only adding the semicolon as a possible delimiter to the pattern:

```
'(^|,|;)(SL)($|,|;)
```

3) remove all semicolons

The complete query

```
SELECT 
    replace(regexp_replace(replace(col1,',',',;'),'(^|,|;)(SL)($|,|;)','\1\3',1,0,'imn'),';') as col2
FROM tab;
```

produce the expected result

```
,PK
PK,
,
(null)
PK
PI,,PK
PI,,,PK
PI,,,,PK
PI,,,,,PK
PI,OSL,,PK
PI,,SLR,PK
```