# Oracle regex count multiple occurrences of a string surrounded by commas

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

This question is similar to a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940076/oracle-regex-replace-multiple-occurrences-of-a-string-surrounded-by-commas) question of mine. I am looking for a way to count a character string in a comma-separated list of values in a column in an Oracle (11g) SQL database. For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
SELECT ('SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('SL,CR,SL') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PK,SL') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('SL,SL') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT ('SL') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT ('PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT ('PI,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PI,OSL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('PI,SL,SLR,PK') as col1 FROM dual

COL1
-----
SL,PK
SL,CR,SL
PK,SL
SL,SL
SL
PK
PI,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK
PI,OSL,SL,PK
PI,SL,SLR,PK
```

I am looking to count all occurrences of the substring 'SL', strictly (i.e. not including 'OSL', 'SLR', etc). **The ideal result would look like this**:

```
COL1                COL2
-----               -----
SL,PK               1
SL,CR,SL            2
PK,SL               1
SL,SL               2
SL                  1
PK                  0
PI,SL,PK            1
PI,SL,SL,PK         2
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK      3
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK   4
PI,OSL,SL,PK        1
PI,SL,SLR,PK        1
```

I can accomplish this using `length` and `regexp_replace`:

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    (length(col1) - NVL(length(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col1,'(^|,)(SL)($|,)','\1' || '' || '\3',1,0,'imn'),'(^|,)(SL)($|,)','\1' || '' || '\3',1,0,'imn')),0))/length('SL') as col2
FROM (
    SELECT ('SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('SL,CR,SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PK,SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('SL,SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('SL') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT ('PI,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,OSL,SL,PK') as col1 FROM dual
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT ('PI,SL,SLR,PK') as col1 FROM dual
)

COL1                COL2
-----               -----
SL,PK               1
SL,CR,SL            2
PK,SL               1
SL,SL               2
SL                  1
PK                  0
PI,SL,PK            1
PI,SL,SL,PK         2
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK      3
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK   4
PI,OSL,SL,PK        1
PI,SL,SLR,PK        1
```

but was hoping for a more elegant solution, perhaps with `regexp_count`. I have achieved my goal successfully in other regex implementations that have the word boundary `\b` construct available (with `\bSL\b`), but have not found a solution for Oracle's regex.

Comment: You should really fix your data model.  Don't store multiple values in a string.  Use a table that has separate rows.  Then you wouldn't be spending your time try to find clever hacks to do what you want.

Comment: I don't disagree, I would much rather have data closer to 3NF, but that is not in my control as I am not a member of our DB team.

Comment: `col1` is a string and `col2` is a count of the occurence of a specific substring (`SL`) in `col1`.

Comment: `col1` is multiple rows, with a different example string in each row. The query will add a second column, `col2`, with the count. Try running the example SQL I have provided. I have also tried to clarify my target example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_count()` if you hack the string:

```
select col1, regexp_count(replace(col1, ',', ',,'), '(^|\W)SL(\W|$)')
```

This doubles the delimiter so the first match doesn't eat it up -- getting around the underlying issue which is that Oracle regular expressions do not support look-ahead.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22f0c19bb10723711bfa6011f5d5156f) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select col1,
  3            regexp_substr(col1, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) val
  4     from test cross join
  5       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ',') + 1
  7                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  8    )
  9  select col1,
 10         sum(case when val = 'SL' then 1 else 0 end) col2
 11  From temp
 12  group by col1;

COL1                    COL2
----------------- ----------
PI,SL,SLR,PK               1
PK,SL                      1
PK                         0
SL,CR,SL                   2
PI,OSL,SL,PK               1
SL,SL                      2
PI,SL,SL,PK                2
PI,SL,SL,SL,PK             3
SL,PK                      1
SL                         1
PI,SL,PK                   1
PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK          4

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `temp` CTE splits each column into rows (separator is comma)
- the final `select` simply counts number of `SL`s for each `col1`

Comment: I think this is going to be what I want, but I wasn't able to completely generalize it to our actual table. What exactly is happening when you call `table()`. I apologize if this is an overly basic question.

Comment: Here, it is used to avoid duplicates as we're dealing with many (OK, *more than one*) row/string. If it weren't for this, you wouldn't need it.

Comment: Are you referring to my sample data as a table named `test`?

Comment: Yes, I named the table TEST.

Comment: If there are identical `col1` values then this solution will group them together and return fewer rows than there actually are in the table.

Comment: Yes, @MT0. Though, I'd expect that table to have some *unique identifier* column which would prevent that. Sample data looks just like that - a *sample*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `XMLTABLE` to spilt the string and then count:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   XMLTABLE(
                  ('"' || REPLACE( col1, ',', '","' ) || '"')
                  COLUMNS
                    value CHAR(2) PATH '.'
                )
         WHERE  value = 'SL'
       ) AS col2
FROM   test_data
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( col1 ) AS
SELECT 'SL,PK'             FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'SL,CR,SL'          FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PK,SL'             FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'SL,SL'             FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'SL'                FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PK'                FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 'PI,SL,PK'          FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PI,SL,SL,PK'       FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PI,SL,SL,SL,PK'    FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK' FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PI,OSL,SL,PK'      FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'PI,SL,SLR,PK'      FROM dual
```

This outputs:

> ```
> COL1              | COL2
> :---------------- | ---:
> SL,PK             |    1
> SL,CR,SL          |    2
> PK,SL             |    1
> SL,SL             |    2
> SL                |    1
> PK                |    0
> PI,SL,PK          |    1
> PI,SL,SL,PK       |    2
> PI,SL,SL,SL,PK    |    3
> PI,SL,SL,SL,SL,PK |    4
> PI,OSL,SL,PK      |    1
> PI,SL,SLR,PK      |    2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1750bc25760c9aae765d10cfac9d7840)*